# python reading a video

Tags: python, opencv, video, imread

I am using Python 2.7.11 and OpenCV 2.4.9. I cannot read a video by using cv2.imread() or cv2.VideoCapture().

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('cam.avi')
print ("open  = ",cap.isOpened())
```

OR

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.imread('cam.avi')
print ("open  = ",cap.isOpened())
```

It will return false.
I don't know why. I am sure that the cam.avi is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try providing full path to video, like:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(r'C:\Users\e01069\Downloads\drop.avi')
print ("open  = ",cap.isOpened())
```

If you run following in your same file, you would know that python is looking for your file on some different location.

```
import os
print os.path.abspath(__file__)  #this is your current working directory
```

**Note:** `.imread` wouldn't work this way.

Comment: cap.isOpened() = False
And I try to read it 
ret, frame = video_capture.read()
print frame
It returns NULL

Comment: video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture("C:\Users\user\Desktop\cam.mp4")
    print ("open  = ",video_capture.isOpened())
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    print frame

Comment: you missed little `r` I mentioned just before the path in my code.. Kindly check the code.

Comment: has to be something with your path, its working pretty fine for me here.

Answer (score 2):

`imread()` does not support reading from video files directly.

See also the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.12/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html) of OpenCV.

If you want to read a video with `imread` you will first have to convert it to single images, either via a serperate program (`ffmpeg` comes to mind) or using OpenCV and store the images in memory.